# How to multiply price and tax percentage to get tax amount automatically with javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery-autocomplete, multiplication

I want to multiply price and tax percentage to get tax amount automatically with javascript.
After I input the price and tax percentage, the text field of tax amount automatically changes into the result of calculation. I developed my web with php and javascript.

`Price      : $<input type="text" class="price" value=""><br/>`

`Tax (%)    : <input type="text" class="dp_per" value="">%<br/>`

`Tax Amount : $<input type="text" class="dp_per" value=""><br/>
<br/>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the values with className and do the math. I used `getElementsByClassName` to match your posted code, but I would give each of these id's and use `getElementById` instead. I bound to the onblur event of the tax as you did not provide any specifications should trigger a recalc of the taxAmount. Make sure that you check this server side too as bypassing client side javascript is trivial.

http://jsfiddle.net/mrtsherman/97hnD/

```
var price = document.getElementsByClassName('price')[0];
var tax = document.getElementsByClassName('dp_per')[0];
var taxAmount = document.getElementsByClassName('dp_per')[1];

tax.onblur = function() {
    taxAmount.value = parseFloat(price.value) * parseFloat(tax.value) / 100;
}
```

​

Comment: thank you mrtsherman :)
it's working..I'm a newbie in web programming hehe
and this is very helpful for me :)
thanks again dude :D

Comment: ah, wait..I've another question about this..the tax amount value changed when the tax field on blur, how about the tax amount changed while i typing on the tax percentage field? can it be?

Comment: if you want it to change dynamically as you type, then it gets more complicated. You can monitor the `keydown`, `keypress` or `keyup` events instead of onblur. This misses cases where people cut and paste values in though. If you need to cover that case then you have to bind to `propertychange` event for most browsers and in addition `input` for Firefox.

Comment: okay, I get it :)
I think I will use 'onblur' event. thanks again @mrtsherman :D